# Why is [b,a] the multiplicative inverse in the field of fraction of an integral domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, integral-domain

$F = (D \times D^{\ast})/\sim = \{[a,b] | b \neq 0\}$ where $[a,b]$ denotes the equivalence class of $(a,b)$. 
Define addition and multiplication as $[a,b] + [c,d] = [ad + bc, bd]$ and $[a,b][c,d] = [ac, bd]$.

I found the multiplicative identity $[1,1]$. The multiplicative inverse produces the element $[ab, ba]$, is this equivalent to $[1,1]$ because $ab=ba$ and neither one has $b = 0$?

The equivalence relation is $(a,b)$~$(c,d)$ if $ad = bc$.

Comment: What is $D$? What is $D^x$? Please explain your notation. You should also learn how to use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/39599).

Comment: $D$ is an integral domain, $D^{\ast}$ is the multiplicative group of the integral domain, so $D \times D^{\ast} = ((a,b) \epsilon D^2 | b \neq 0)$

Comment: $[1,1]$ is the multiplicative *identity*. You will need to use the (undefined in your post) equivalence relation.

Comment: Yes, that was my mistake, which is corrected! The equivalence relation is (a,b)~(c,d) if ad = bc.

Comment: @confused If $x\ne0$, then $(x,x)\in D\times D^*$ and $(x,x)\sim(1,1)$.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. The title says you want to know why $[a,b]$ and $[b,a]$ are inverses,  but you seem to have shown that $[a,b][b,a]\sim [1,1]$, so it's not clear what you want to know.

Comment: @confused: If you didn't notice $[a,b]$ acts exactly the same way $\frac{a}{b}$ acts in $\mathbb{Q}$, the field of quotients of $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @MJD I was more or less trying to understand if that was the actual logic behind [ab, ba] = [1,1]. I'm more or less asking is the reason they are equal because they are the same equivalence class.

Answer (score 0):

$$[a,b][b,a]=\cdots\sim[1,1]\qquad\text{because...}$$